# Не выводится элемент массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Пробую вывести один из элементов массива (первый), в итоге ничего не выводится. 
Код:

```js
var arrayMap[
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
];
document.write(arrayMap[0]);
```

По логике, должно вывести "1". В чём моя ошибка?

Comment: а что выводит? Как файл подключаете? попробуйте `console.log` вместо `document.write`

Comment: = после arrayMap

Comment: Вам даже сниппет сообщает что у вас встречен неправильный символ `[`. Данный вопрос следует закрыть, т.к. вызван опечаткой, и вряд ли поможет будущим пользователям.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arrayMap = [
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
];
document.write(arrayMap[0]);
```

Синтаксическая ошибка, не хватает оператора присваивания после имени переменной.

Comment: Благодарю. Не заметил.